# C# Winforms - Controls not rendering completely

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created an user control which contains a `Panel`, and the panel contains 4 more components. It is supposed to look something like this:

*Component rendering correctly*

[image: Component rendering correctly]

---

And it actually renders this way in some parts of the form. However, in other parts of the form, it renders like this:

*Component rendering incorrectly*

[image: Component rendering incorrectly]

Basically, the part with the checkboxes is completely missing and even a part of the combo is missing. Now I should add, that this is inside another `UserControl`, but, as far as I know, this should not effect anything.

---

Another thing I should mention is, that without anchoring to the right the controls renders correctly everywhere. I tried anchoring the components without the panel, but it rendered incorrectly everywhere. Now, I have the components anchored inside the panel, which works fine, but as the panel itself is not anchored, it does not resize correctly. Anchoring the `Panel` breaks it in the same way as anchoring individual components does.

What has partially solved this problem was this piece of code:

```
private void Component_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlContainer.Size = new Size(this.Width, this.Height);
}
```

It solves rendering in some places, but in others, the problem stays. It makes sense to me, that the code I've added to the Resize handler would fix the problem in all cases. What could be the cause of this problem and is there a possible solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Check the size of your UserControl and your Font Size too, if you want it to fit you have to use the same (or less) size, or just anchor/dock the items to handle these kind of problems.

Comment: **[Creating a DPI-Aware Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms701681(v=vs.85).aspx)**  There are also gobs of posts here on the topic if you search.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: @Filip Welcome at stackoverflow, it is good to visit the [Tour Page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) before getting started *(also to get your first Informed badge)*

Comment: I have been searching for the last several hours, unfortunately, I've been unable to find the answer. I'm not a native speaker, so I unfortunately don't always know how to phrase the question well.